# Combining Silky Skin Bioware & Implant Medics Nanoware

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

**Augmentation** (page 63) details the Cosmetic Bioware augment *Silky Skin*. It is a treatment after which your body grows new, super smooth skin which can be marked or marred by new damage/scars.

**Augmentation** (page 108) has the nanoware system *Implant Medics*. It says that when you add this option to a bio- or cyberware, it has nanites that monitor the health and repair damage to the implant.

Would *implant medics* purchased with *silky skin* allow the skin to be healed back to the smooth state by, as *implant medics* describes as part of its functions, "sealing fractures, removing damaged tissue, and so on"?

Would this give a character a low-level regeneration? Or would it mean that after the character finished healing the skin is unmarred?

Comment: It would almost certainly not improve healing speed; medically the bad parts of an injury aren't just when the skin's broken. This leaves someone open to infection, but it's the actual arterial, skeletal, muscular, or organ damage that occurs with a wound that is dangerous.

That said, the skin would probably heal unmarred with the help of Implant Medics.

Comment: @KyleWilley I could actually see some funny situations where the skin is healed on top of an open wound, leading to worse complications...

Comment: That is the line I was thinking. But I wanted to bounce it off other GMs to give me more standing against my rules-lawyer players. Thanks

Comment: @Scrollmaster I don't have a huge medical background, but it would really be essentially the same as having a very good bandage on, so I doubt we'd see huge complications. Maybe you'd have to pick off an extra layer of skin, but you have the Implant Medics for that.

Comment: Regeneration (upper case, the one with specific rules) or regeneration (lower case, handled under normal healing rules)?

Answer (score 8):

As far as the rules go, *Implant Medics* repair **just the implant** they belong to. *Silky Skin* is a valid target to be repaired. So far, nothing special. Now, keep in mind that *Silky Skin* is a **cosmetic implant**, that can be tarnished or "damaged" by scars, new tattoos, piercings etc. So it is easy to see that *Implant Medics* can repair said damage. The nanoware will do their best to mend away the new scars, bleach out the henna paint, close the piercing channel once it is taken out and otherwise keep the skin silky and smooth. So in SOME way one could say it is a very, very mild regeneration<sup>lower case!</sup> of the skin only.

However, this combination does not fix any boxes of damage, as damage is more than just "cut skin": a single box of physical damage stands for deeper cuts into the muscles below the skin, broken bones, even cut off body parts... and all this does not only affect the *Silky Skin* alone but a lot of other body parts as well. So as the result, the *Implant Medics* can't fix up your whole body.

The only way to achieve *Regeneration*<sup>upper case!</sup> in a rule sense<sup>iirc</sup> is through magic. For example you could be a Shapeshifter or gain it from a Spirit.

---

## Examples

Adam "Jinx" Alt is a mundane face and has no implants. On a run he gets hit by a shiawase guard's flamethrower and the skin is badly burnt. After spending his time (as healing rules!) at a doctor and then resting at home for a few weeks, he looks pretty hiddiously burnt where he was hit. Now he gets *Silky Skin*, and when he leaves the tank the burn scars are gone.

Now, Adam goes back to try the run again... and promptly gets the same result of being burnt heavily. His *Silky Skin* doesn't prevent any damage, and it ripples up into the same scars that he had had just removed. Indeed, the implant could even be seen as having been (largely) damaged! So once again, the marathon through the doctor's office and healing downtime is ensured. This time, he gets himself a new *Silky Skin* (no new essence costs, as he replaces the old with the new) and adds the *Implant Medics* to it.

And once again Adam tries the same run (he never learns), and again he gets hit by the burning fuel of the Shiawase guard's weapon. And again, the *Silky Skin* is burnt heavily and the flesh under it cooked. Again, he goes to the doctor, rests a few weeks at home to heal the damage. But this time he doesn't have to get a new *Silky Skin*, as his new *Implant Medics* fix up his looks. He still had to heal the damage as usual though.

Comment: Burn me once, shame on you. Burn me twice, shame on me. Burn me thrice... aw heck, I dunno...

Answer (score 3):

Yes the skin will be unmarred, but it will only repair the skin not the actual damage done to underlying organs/tissue. So no regeneration, but you could argue that it would make the character a little bit more resistant to infections becuase of open wounds